# Template does not exists

Tags: django

estoy utilizando el framework de python Django para desarrollar una página web, pero tengo el siguiente problema y espero que alguien pueda ayudarme.

El error que me tira en la consola es "django.templates.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExists: projects.html".

Este es mi archivo views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse, redirect

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("""<h1>Inicio</h1>""")

    return render(request, 'index.html')


def projects(request):

    return render(request, 'projects.html' )
```

urls.py:

Aca tengo mis rutas definidas por ahora.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from miapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('inicio/', views.index, name='inicio'),
    path('projects/', views.projects, name='projects')

]
```

templates/miapp/projects.html:

```
{%extends 'layout.html'%}
```

Answer (score 0):

Verifica si en tu archivo settings tiene configurado el templates, y tambien creando una carpeta templates donde tengas todos tus html, ejemplo:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```